# Disable 2FA via Sandbox refresh Apex class?

Tags: two-factor-authentication

Is it possible to change/disable 2FA settings via Apex or API?

This comes up as an issue during Sandbox refreshes, when users are enrolled in 2FA using their email, but the sandbox has automatically changed their address to 'user@domain.com.INVALID', so they can't actually get the 2FA email.

Since we don't have the same security concerns in sandbox, it would be simpler to disable 2FA than another workaround (like updating user email addresses to allow 2fa to work)

[image]

Comment: It depends on your implementation of 2FA, please update your question with more details.

Comment: @identigral I'm not sure what you're looking for so I added a screenshot of the 'Session Settings' screen in setup, the only way I know of currently to enable/disable 2FA.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The session settings are applied at the org level as well as at the profile level. Profile-level settings override the org-wide settings...but some session settings cannot be changed at the profile level. Notably, configuring a session security level by mapping the authentication method to a Standard vs High level is only possible at the org level.

*Applying* the session security level by specifying what level is *required* at login time is done on a per-profile basis. You could have a profile that requires a High Assurance session and therefore triggers 2-factor authentication and a profile that doesn't require it. When you clone and/or refresh your sandbox, you can automatically assign the right profile to your users via a [post-install script.](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_interface_System_SandboxPostCopy.htm)

Comment: Excellent, did not realize that, thank you!

Comment: How will this work if you disable it on a profile basis if the user itself is already enrolled in MFA?